# iOS Get Values of Controls in UITableViewCells

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

So, I'm a bit of a noob to iOS (PHP dev).  I have a UITableView in a UIViewController.  The cells consist of a combination of any of three different custom prototype cells.  Which cells are loaded is based on a service that loads the questions and types.  One has a segmented control with 2 choices, another with 8 choices and the third has a UITextView to receive a comment.  This is essentially a survey.  I can grab the values of the controls as they are answered, but I'd like to be able to just gather them up when the 'submitResponses()' method is called as an action attached to the 'Submit' button.

Any ideas?  Should I be going about this in another way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" way to do this is definitely to collect the data as it is entered!

One of the biggest problems with the approach that you suggest is that for larger tables it simply won't work because if a table view cell is off the screen, you can't access it or the controls/views that it contains (and it may not even exist yet!).

Comment: Ok, understood. Like to yell huh? Mad at me?  haha, anyway, so is it not possible?  I suppose I'll snag the answer as it's pressed, pop it in an array and then loop through the array on 'Submit' to validate.

But just for kicks, how would you qualify the "correct" way?

Comment: Haha, nope, not yelling!  You typically create variables that you save each value to as they are created.  In this example, I would create three appropriate variables (bool or int, int or a string representing the value of the segmented control, and NSString).  When you hit submit just look at the info saved in the variables and don't worry about the form.